# Stand-alone Use of 'There' in English

Tags: expressions, word-usage

I was reading *The Invisible Man* by H.G.Wells. He uses *There!* without connection to other words (or maybe there is connection, but I don't see it).

> She glanced at his white-swathed head and blue goggles again as she was going out of the door; but his napkin was still in front of his face. She shivered a little as she closed the door behind her, and her face was eloquent of her surprise and perplexity. "I *never*," she whispered. **"There!"** She went quite softly to the kitchen, and was too preoccupied to ask Millie what she was messing about with now, when she got there.

What is the meaning of "There" in this context?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[There!](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/there):

> interjection. Used to express feelings such as relief, satisfaction, sympathy, or anger. - TFD

Often, it's not alone. *There, there* is meant to comfort. *There you go* can mean you've got everything you need to be off. But used alone, it expresses an emotion.

> There! That ought to hold the little bastards." - Uncle Don (disproven)

Answer (score 1):

Note that "there" is used as an exclamation. In this case it expresses finality or one-upmanship in the confrontation with the other person.